# virtualenv vs virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django development and stuck at installing part of Django. Actually, before running the following cmd, everyone told me to create virtual enviroment but I got confused about whether I have to install virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper or both.

```
py -m pip install Django
```

Many tutorials on youtube show the installation using

```
pip install virtualenv
```

but I installed

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

and surprisingly it also work. Will anyone tell me which one I have to use to use virtual environment. Also in most of the youtube tutorials after installing virtualenv they get bin folder but in my case no such folder exists...

please  fully guide me regarding installation in windows for django:)

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the doc? https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> virtualenvwrapper is a set of extensions to Ian Bicking’s virtualenv
>   tool. The extensions include wrappers for creating and deleting
>   virtual environments and otherwise managing your development workflow,
>   making it easier to work on more than one project at a time without
>   introducing conflicts in their dependencies.

Comment: ya I read but should I install  virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper that's  I am asking

Comment: It depends on what you need for your project. If you don't know exactly what do you need, or it's the first time you use virtual environment, I think both are good for you, just take one from them to go on.